# Implementation of signaling server for Android which will use webRTC using java

Tags: java, spring-mvc, webrtc

I am going to implement webRTC for voice and video call, for this i would be needing a signalling server first.Can anyone please send me some links or some guidance for the implementation of the signalling server using java.

Comment: You server will be on Android or will just connect with android devices? Simply create a page and going to Chrome will not suffice or does it have to be an app?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to build signalling server using java, you can use sip servlet.

[Sip Servlet](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19355-01/820-3007/gfmpq/index.html)

> A SIP servlet is a Java programming language server-side component
>   that performs SIP signalling. SIP servlets are managed by a SIP
>   servlet container, which typically are part of a SIP-enabled
>   application server

See also mobicent implemention on sip servlet [mobicent](http://www.mobicents.org/products_sip_servlets.html)
And also see JainSip for signalling server [JSIP](https://jsip.java.net/)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about java. But you can try node.js(JavaScript) and socket.io to set up a signalling server.

Go to the signalling section of the following link:
http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webrtc/basics/

If you want to try java, try setting up a websocket server to handle data from browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I prefer to use  [PeerJs](http://peerjs.com) (Javascript) as the signally server. Peerjs is built on node.js and provide a lot friendly API for user to implement signalling.

I have no idea whether you can do it with JAVA. But JavaScript seems a better choose to build a signalling server.

To implement a signalling server, [This](http://blog.davidvassallo.me/2014/02/07/got-15-minutes-easy-webrtc-android-app-in-3-steps/) tutorial should be a very good example about how to do it with Peerjs and Crosswalk.

Answer (score 0):

You can also have a look at RestComm http://restcomm.com/ and https://github.com/Mobicents/RestComm.

It already contains :

- a WebRTC client : http://www.telestax.com/livechat-and-video-call-with-restcomm/
- a WebRTC Client Side Javascript framework
- an Android SDK https://github.com/Mobicents/restcomm-android-sdk/
- an iOS SDk https://github.com/Mobicents/restcomm-ios-sdk.

Of course, everything is open source so any contributions are welcome ;) !